# parse multiple tables into one csv with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

i have a csv file where all tables are underneath each other. All tables have a MasterId with which I could link them. Currently I try it with pandas.pivot_table

Here how the csv looks like now

```
masterId featureName featureValue
1        bar         fooo
2        bar         x
3        bar         y
4        bar         z

masterId featureName featureValue
1        zzz         m
2        zzz         p
3        zzz         q
4        zzz         r

              .
              .
              .
```

How i want it to look like

```
masterId    bar   zzz
1           foo   m
2           x     p
3           y     q
4           z     r
```

Here my code to transpose

```
transposedTables = pd.pivot_table(
untransposedDataFrame,
index=["masterId"],
columns=["featureName"],
values=["featureValue"],
aggfunc=[np.sum],
dropna=True)

transposedTables.to_csv('./transposed_export_07012019.csv')
```

But some values remain empty although there is an entry for it

```
masterId    bar   zzz
1                 m
2                 p
3           y    
4
```

Do you have an idea why the fields are empty? It has about 50 Tables with each 20k lines and 19mb. After the pivot_table it should have 50 columns with about 20k lines

i would be happy about hints

Answer (score 0):

If you can access each table and pivot it, then all you need is to merge. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'masterId': [1,2,3,4], 
                          'featureName': ['bar','bar','bar','bar'],
                          'featureValue': ['foo','x','y','z']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'masterId': [1,2,3,4], 
                          'featureName': ['zzz','zzz','zzz','zzz'],
                          'featureValue': ['m','p','q','r']})

transposedTable1 = pd.pivot_table(
df1,
index=["masterId"],
columns=["featureName"],
values=["featureValue"],
aggfunc=[np.sum],
dropna=True)  

transposedTable2 = pd.pivot_table(
df2,
index=["masterId"],
columns=["featureName"],
values=["featureValue"],
aggfunc=[np.sum],
dropna=True)   

df = transposedTable1.merge(transposedTable2, on='masterId',  how='inner')
```

This produces your expected df but with different column names, which is easy to handle and change if you note that df is a MultiIndex ( verify that with `df.columns` )

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because some indicies in `masterId` index columns don' match. First, let's look when it works correctly:

```
untransposedDataFrame = pd.concat((df1, df2))  # df1, df2 from your example

untransposedDataFrame                                                                                                                                                                  
Out: 

         featureName featureValue
masterId                         
1                zzz          foo
2                zzz            x
3                zzz            y
4                zzz            z
1                bar            m
2                bar            p
3                bar            q
4                bar            r
```

`masterId` in `df1` and `df2` matches, so it works OK:

```
pd.pivot_table( 
    untransposedDataFrame, 
    index=["masterId"], 
    columns=["featureName"], 
    values=["featureValue"], 
    aggfunc=[np.sum], 
    dropna=True)      

Out:
                     sum     
            featureValue     
featureName          bar  zzz
masterId                     
1                      m  foo
2                      p    x
3                      q    y
4                      r    z
```

I guess, actually in your case indicies in untransposedDataFrame don't match:

```
untransposedDataFrame                                                                                                                                                                 
Out: 
         featureName featureValue
masterId                         
1                zzz          foo
2                zzz            x
3                zzz            y
4                zzz            z
5                bar            m
6                bar            p
7                bar            q
8                bar            r
```

Modifying DataFrame:

```
pd.pivot_table( 
    untransposedDataFrame, 
    index=["masterId"], 
    columns=["featureName"], 
    values=["featureValue"], 
    aggfunc=[np.sum], 
    dropna=True)

Out: 
                     sum     
            featureValue     
featureName          bar  zzz
masterId                     
1                    NaN  foo
2                    NaN    x
3                    NaN    y
4                    NaN    z
5                      m  NaN
6                      p  NaN
7                      q  NaN
8                      r  NaN
```

**Solution 0**
If there are a missed values, it's a feature - `masterId` does not match in two tables, so keep it in mind and in data.

**Solution 1 (bad)**
Ignore `masterId` (may not fit most cases). Reset indicies:

```
df1_reset = df1.reset_index() 
df2_reset = df2.reset_index() 
df1_reset                                                                                                                                                                             

Out: 
   masterId featureName featureValue
0         1         zzz          foo
1         2         zzz            x
2         3         zzz            y
3         4         zzz            z

untransposedDataFrameReset = pd.concat((df1_reset, df2_reset)) 
untransposedDataFrameReset.index.name = "newIndex"
```

Now it looks like:

```
untransposedDataFrameReset 

Out: 
          masterId featureName featureValue
newIndex                                   
0                1         zzz          foo
1                2         zzz            x
2                3         zzz            y
3                4         zzz            z
0                5         bar            m
1                6         bar            p
2                7         bar            q
3                8         bar            r
```

So, it could be transposed, but `masterId` just lost:

```
    untransposedDataFrame, 
    index=["newIndex"], 
    columns=["featureName"], 
    values=["featureValue"], 
    aggfunc=[np.sum], 
    dropna=True)

Out: 
                     sum     
            featureValue     
featureName          bar  zzz
newIndex                     
0                      m  foo
1                      p    x
2                      q    y
3                      r    z
```

**Solution 2 (looks better)**
Do the same "reindex" steps as in Solution 1, you shoul get:

```
unstackedDataFrameReset

Out:
          masterId featureName featureValue
newIndex                                   
0                1         zzz          foo
1                2         zzz            x
2                3         zzz            y
3                4         zzz            z
0                5         bar            m
1                6         bar            p
2                7         bar            q
3                8         bar            r
```

It's important - a `newIndex` values should match for the lines you plan to aggregate, and `masterId` should be a column. Make a `featureName` new index level andunstack DataFrame by it:

```
untransposedDataFrameReset.set_index("featureName", append=True).unstack()                                                                                                            
Out[149]: 
            masterId     featureValue     
featureName      bar zzz          bar  zzz
newIndex                                  
0                  5   1            m  foo
1                  6   2            p    x
2                  7   3            q    y
3                  8   4            r    z
```

So, you don't loose a `masterId` index and don't get NaN values. But that case you ignore the fact that some id's don't match.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Not every feature has the same number of entries. I did not notice with the mass

Comment: Does the `masterId` matters after all, or you can drop it?

Comment: I need it later, to get the user.